# combine three tables in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having these three tables

Table A:

```
code        aname
----------- ----------
1           A
2           B
3           C
```

Table B:

```
code        bname
----------- ----------
1           aaa
1           bbb
2           ccc
2           ddd
```

Table C

```
code        cname
----------- ----------
1           xxx  
1           yyy
1           zzz
2           www
```

How can I achieve the output like this using single query ?

```
code        aname      bname       cname
----------- ---------- ----------  ----------
1           A          aaa         xxx
1           A          bbb         yyy
1           A          NULL        zzz
2           B          ccc         www
2           B          ddd         NULL
3           C          NULL        NULL
```

Any suggestions ?

Thanks

Comment: By what rule do you combine `aaa` with `xxx` and not with `yyy` or `zzz`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want "lists" to be vertical for tables `B` and `C`.  This is doable, by using `row_number()`.  However, the trick is getting the third row in where there are no matches.

Here is one method.  It uses a full outer join to combine the `b` and `c` names together.  It then uses `left join` to bring in the `a` records.

```
select a.code, a.name, bc.bname, bc.cname
from a left join
     (select coalesce(b.code, c.code) as code, bname, cname
      from (select code, bname, NULL as cname,
                    row_number() over (partition by code order by code) as seqnum
            from b
           ) b full outer join
           (select code, NULL as bname, cname,
                    row_number() over (partition by code order by code) as seqnum
            from c
           ) c
           on b.code = c.code and b.seqnum = c.seqnum
      ) bc
      on bc.code = a.code;
```